# stream insight dispose problem

Tags: streaminsight

i have written a small app with stream insight just to learn this stuff.
the app works fine but when i close the app when disposing the cep server the app freezes.
event though all the adapters a no longer working - called stopped
i am using typed point adapters
thanks and sorry for the stupid question....

Answer (score 0):

On disposing the StreamInsight server, it waits one minute for the adapters to finish. Does your app eventually exit after one minute?

Answer (score 0):

Are you notifying the engine that your adapters have stopped successfully? You need to call Stopped() on the adapter base class.